# При парсинге данных получаю пустой список

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Надо спарсить необходимые данные, они на сайте размещены но при попытке парсинга я получаю пустой список.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
URL = 'https://auto.ria.com/uk/legkovie/jeep/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36', 
'accept': 'application/json'}
HOST = 'https://auto.ria.com'


def get_html (url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r
def get_pages_count(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    pagination = soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'page-item mhide')
    if pagination:
        return int(pagination[4].get_text())
    else :
        return 1
    

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('section', class_='ticket-item new__ticket')
    cars = []
    for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title': item.find('div', class_='item ticket-title').get_text(strip=True)})
    return cars

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        cars = []
        pages_count = get_pages_count(html.text)
        for page in range(1, pages_count + 1):
            print(f'Парсинг страницы {page} из {pages_count}...')
            html = get_html(URL, params={'page': page})
            cars.extend(get_content(html.text))                     
        
    else:
        print('Error')
    print(cars)
parse()
ответ:
Парсинг страницы 1 из 5...
Парсинг страницы 2 из 5...
Парсинг страницы 3 из 5...
Парсинг страницы 4 из 5...
Парсинг страницы 5 из 5...
[]
```

Comment: `soup.find_all('section', class_='ticket-item new__ticket')` нечего не смог найти

Comment: После пробела в классе а точнее new__ticket уже считается подклассом, и bs4 его не записывает в класс для исправления надо просто в класс записать весь текст до первого пробела в классе.

Answer (score 2):

Замените эту строчку `items = soup.find_all('section', class_='ticket-item new__ticket')`
На эту `items = soup.find_all('section', class_='ticket-item')`
После пробела в класс нечего не записывается после парсинга в частых случаях.

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ответ Ивана. find_all даёт искать по критерию ИЛИ. Если нужно, чтобы обязательно были оба класса, то можно искать так:

```
items = soup.select('section.ticket-item.new__ticket')
```

Comment: Спасибо что дополнили меня, не знал что можно таким способом искать оба класса.